# Cant acces rabbitmq through the web interface?

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed rabbitmq on a 14 ubuntu, adjusted the hostname in the /etc/hosts files, in the following format `127.0.0.1 hostname`.

I can see the web console with **curl localhost:15672**, but when I try to access it with the browser, it just won't open?

I can see the port with netstat:

```
netstat -nptl | grep 15672

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29997/beam
```

But I can't see it with nmap:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-16 19:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
631/tcp open  ipp
```

I also enabled the web interface in rabbitmq, made the user and all that, but when I try to access it through the browser http:/my-ip-address:15672(5672), the web page just times out?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: maybe the firewall?

Comment: no, I've turned everything off...I'm starting to pull my hair off :)

Comment: and I don't get how come nmap doesn't say that the rabbitmq port is open(port closed), but netstat does?

Comment: just found the answer, provider that gives me the virtual lab restricted the ports in question because of security reasons, that's the reason it wasn't working correctly...